# How can I get an iPhone to play songs in order

Tags: iphone, itunes

I'm trying to listen to an album on my iPhone. The play plays the songs randomly. I would like to hear the album in sequence.

I also have playlists that I'd like to listen to in sequence.

When I look at the list of songs in the playlist the controls at the top available to me are "Edit" "Clear" "Delete" and under that "Shuffle". But "Shuffle" doesn't seem to be a toggle switch. It's more like it means "reshuffle."

So anyway where do I set the music play to just play the songs in order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it possible that you have shuffle enabled? The shuffle button in the playlist list is not a toggle, so that wouldn't tell you. Here's how you can find out:

[image]

If the shuffle icon is blue, it means your iPhone is playing on shuffle.

Something else you could check is if Shake to Shuffle is enabled:

[image]

If it is, you could accidentally activate shuffle without knowing it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you take the screenshots in new iOS (7, 8 or 9)?

Answer (score 7):

Since iOS 8.4, you can play songs in sequence by clicking on the 1st song; when the song title is showing at the bottom, drag it up and you will see the controls. Unlock the shuffle button by clicking on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on an iPhone 6 plus IOS 8.4.1, if that matters.  To get my songs to play in order (not shuffle), I hit the song bar at the bottom of the screen as the first song was playing.  When that opened, I shut off **both** the shuffle icon (interlocking arrows) **and** the straight icon (looped arrows.) With both of them off (not highlighted), my music plays in order.  Go figure.....